# jQuery UI Accordion - Internet Explorer ugly box shadow after slide effekt

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

Can someone tell me please, how to avoid the ugly box-shadow in Internet Explorer? After the accordion has closed, the box-shadow of the parent DIV has a ugly effect.

It only happens on an absolute positioned parent DIV:

The JavaScript:

> $(function() {
>        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
>            heightStyle: "content",
>            collapsible: true,
>            active: false
>        }); });

The CSS:

> ## accordion{
>
> ```
> box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #999;
> position:absolute;
> width:400px; }
> ```

Here is a fiddle (please open in Internet Explorer)

http://jsfiddle.net/9s5bb/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say, but remove the box-shadow effect (on #accordion) for IE Browsers (i guess, only IE9 or less). IE is not a great browser to manipulate an animation with "modern" effects (even with filter attribute on css). I recommend you to use something like Progressive Enhancement (or Graceful Degradation) and have less stress with old versions of this browser.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Our customer uses the IE9. So I`ve created the drop-sgadow with CSS3 and the gradients with SVG images. I thought that the IE9 is a "more" modern browser. But the ugly effect is still in IE 10 :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a browser bug, but if you specify a `height` value in your CSS the ugly shadow effect disappears:

http://jsfiddle.net/9s5bb/7/

Comment: Yes, the fixed height on the parent will fix the problem. Unfortunately, I`ve mixed the Superfish navigation with a accordion. So I can`t use a fixed height becouse the flyout of the navigation is dynamically. I´ve updated the fiddle, so you can see how I`ve mixed the Superfish navigation with a 3. level accordion: http://jsfiddle.net/9s5bb/11/